# Prevent Windows 11 from going to sleep after RDP session was closed

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, sleep

While there are several threads about Windows RDP sessions and sleep I could not find one matching my use case.

I encounter the following situation. After I close the RDP connection to a Windows 11 system it immediately goes to sleep. Also if the connection is lost the remote computer goes to sleep and I have to turn it on again before I can reconnect.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? It would be OK if it goes to sleep after a time of inactivity, but not right after disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force its sleep state, ie turn screen off, but dont put computer into sleep.

You can do this with by going to start menu, typing "Edit Power Plan", then under option "Turn off the display" put any time like 1minute, and for "Put the computer to sleep" put on never. You can also run CMD(elevated) with;

```
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -monitor-timeout-ac 1
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -monitor-timeout-dc 1

%windir%\system32\Powercfg /change -standby-timeout-ac 0
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -standby-timeout-dc 0
```

In addition you might wanna drop eye on hibernation and disable that too, thru gui or CMD(0 means Never);

```
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
```

If that is Laptop you connect to, check also "Choose what closing the lid does" and set all to do nothing.